# Oracle select with subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

Could you please help me with next oracle sql query.

```
SELECT "NEWS"."NEWSID" as ID,
       "NEWS"."SLUG",
       "NEWS_TRANSLATION".*, 
       (SELECT FILENAME FROM NEWS_MEDIA WHERE NEWSID = ID AND rownum <= 1 ORDER BY POSITION ASC) as FILENAME
FROM "NEWS" 
INNER JOIN "NEWS_TRANSLATION" ON NEWS.NEWSID = NEWS_TRANSLATION.NEWSID 
WHERE (NEWS.PUBLISH = 1) AND (NEWS_TRANSLATION.LANG = :lang) 
ORDER BY "NEWS"."NEWSID" DESC;
```

When I execute this query I have error

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 74
```

Comment: If the intention is to get the filename of the MIN position for a news  item from news_media, I don't think rownum is being used correctly. The "ORDER BY" is being applied after one record is selected. It would need to be subqueried or, better yet, joined separately with MIN(position).  See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2006/06-sep/o56asktom-086197.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT "NEWS"."NEWSID" as ID,
   "NEWS"."SLUG",
   "NEWS_TRANSLATION".*, 
   (SELECT * FROM (SELECT FILENAME FROM NEWS_MEDIA WHERE NEWSID = ID ORDER BY POSITION ASC) WHERE rownum = 1) as FILENAME
FROM "NEWS" 
INNER JOIN "NEWS_TRANSLATION" ON NEWS.NEWSID = NEWS_TRANSLATION.NEWSID 
WHERE (NEWS.PUBLISH = 1) AND (NEWS_TRANSLATION.LANG = :lang) 
ORDER BY "NEWS"."NEWSID" DESC;
```

When are you are using "order by" and "rownum" together, you need to first order them and look for the first record.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the working *code*:

```
SELECT "NEWS"."NEWSID" as ID,
   "NEWS"."SLUG",
   "NEWS_TRANSLATION".*, 
   (SELECT FILENAME FROM NEWS_MEDIA WHERE NEWSID = ID AND rownum <= 1 ) as FILENAME
FROM "NEWS" 
INNER JOIN "NEWS_TRANSLATION" ON NEWS.NEWSID = NEWS_TRANSLATION.NEWSID 
WHERE (NEWS.PUBLISH = 1) AND (NEWS_TRANSLATION.LANG = :lang) 
ORDER BY "NEWS"."NEWSID" DESC
```

Comment: The same `Error at Line: 4 Column: 51`

Comment: I changed ID to NEWS.NEWSID in subquery and all works good. But how I can do it with ORDER BY?

Comment: What do you want to show by `order by`? Is it `ORDER BY POSITION ASC` part like in your question?

Comment: Every file have position and I want get the file where position is first. I can write something like `WHERE POSITION = 1`, but I can't be sure that file exist with position, 1, that's why I use `ORDER BY` clause

Answer (score 1):

Please try by removing the order by clause in the sub-query.

Comment: SELECT FILENAME FROM NEWS_MEDIA WHERE NEWSID = ID AND rownum <= 1; I am not sure about the column name ID, please confirm that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
SELECT "NEWS"."NEWSID" AS ID, "NEWS"."SLUG", "NEWS_TRANSLATION".*,
       (SELECT FILENAME
          FROM NEWS_MEDIA
         WHERE NEWSID = "NEWS"."NEWSID" AND ROWNUM <= 1)
           AS FILENAME
  FROM     "NEWS"
       INNER JOIN
           "NEWS_TRANSLATION"
       ON NEWS.NEWSID = NEWS_TRANSLATION.NEWSID
 WHERE (NEWS.PUBLISH = 1) AND (NEWS_TRANSLATION.LANG = :LANG)
ORDER BY "NEWS"."NEWSID" DESC
```

Comment: When your subquery returns only one value foreach record in main query, then why are you trying to sort the subquery??

Comment: I answer for your question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11794242/oracle-select-with-subquery#comment15674817_11796362

Comment: @Pivasyk My question is: What is the purpose of sorting in subquery?

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_ALIAS_NAME
FROM school
WHERE STUDENT_NAME IN (
        SELECT STUDENT_NAME
        FROM school
        WHERE STUDENT_DEPARMENT= 0
        );
```

Comment: While this may answer the question, please back up your code with an explanation as to why it will work and why it is better than the other answers.